# I18N considerations in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, localization, internationalization

My Company is considering using Elastic Search and we are evaluating it for various parameters such as scalability, security, internationalization etc. I need to understand the i18n capabilities and best practices around i18n while using ElasticSearch. I am unable to find any good document to refer. Is there any set of best practices in ElasticSearch around i18n?

Answer (score 1):

a lot of it will come down to the language specific analyser that you want to use, you can see what is available here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis.html

other than than, understanding your use case further would allow more advice. but there isn't a single documented approach